# Existence of neutral element at a certain position in subgroups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, equivalence-relations

Given a group $G$ with neutral element $e$ and a subgroup $H \leq G$ as well as the equivalence relation $g_1 \sim g_2 \Leftrightarrow g_2^{-1} g_1 \in H$ (equivalence classes $[g]$). G be finite.

Prove that for all $g \in G: g^{|G|} = e$

This homework consisted of several prior tasks: Existence of bijective function between classes, Lagrange and existence of $k \in \mathbb{N}: g^k = e$, I was able to show those but am stuck on the final one.

So far I only found that if k divides |G|, then obviously $g^{n}=(g^k)^{\frac{n}{k} \in \mathbb{N}}=e$.

Comment: You define your equivalence relation but never use it; is 'prove that $g^{|G|}=e$' the entirety of your question?  If so, then you don't need the subgroup at all...

Comment: Yes, that was the whole question. The subgroup was used in the other parts, but I think it is relevant here, too. The idea being a proof might go along the lines of showing that $g^{|H|} = e$, I am not sure how though (maybe it is in fact not required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Lagrange's theorem then you're most of the way home: you know that for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, $|H|$ divides $|G|$; if $k$ is the order of the subgroup $H=\langle g\rangle$, then what can you say about $g^k$?

Comment: What do you mean by "$\langle g^i\rangle$"?

Comment: @mafutrct Sorry, mental slip: that should be $\langle g\rangle$, the group generated by the element $g$: that is, the group of all elements of the form $g^i$ for some $i$ (you should be able to convince yourself, if you don't already know, that this is a group!).

Comment: Ah thanks, yes. Still stuck though - $g^k$ is an element in the induced subgroup of g which should already exist within $g^{0\leq i<k}$, i.e. it is a duplicate. I believe that even $g^k=e$, but I don't see why this is mandatory at this particular position (k).

Comment: @mafutrct Suppose $k$ is the order of $\langle g\rangle$ and that $g^k=g^j$ for some $0\lt j\lt k$ (i.e., $g^k\neq e$).  What is $g^{k-j}$?  Do you see the contradiction?

Comment: By definition, $g^{k-i} g^i = g^k$. Since $g^i = g^k$, it follows that $g^{k-i} = e$. This means that e must be contained earlier than k, unless $g^k=e$. But why is that a contradiction?

Comment: @mafutrct Because we _defined_ $k$ as the order of the subgroup; if there were some smaller value $m$ (here, $k-j$) with $g^m=e$ then the order of $\langle g\rangle$ would be $m$.  ($e, g, g^2, \ldots, g^{m-1}$ are all the elements of $\langle g\rangle$)

Comment: Obviously! Looking at it from this angle, why is it even a problem at all? :)